# Find value between two data range in MySql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with three fields id,minvalue and maxvalue.These fields carries multiple values like...

```
id Minvalue  maxvalue
 1  100        200
 2  201        300
 3  301        400
```

...and so on. If I supply 250 as input, how can I retrieve its corresponding id using mysql query?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for edited it for more readability

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 250 BETWEEN maxvalue AND minvalue
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Id FROM table WHERE 250 BETWEEN MinValue AND MaxValue
```